# When do the multi colored fish appear on level completion?

Tags: candy-crush-saga

Sometimes after completing a level, it triggers a fish animation that goes around destroying blocks that can substantially increase the score (and help push it past the 2nd or 3rd star levels). I am not choosing any bonus option for this.

Under what circumstances does this happen, and what can be done by the player to increase chance to trigger it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fish are triggered at 3 fish per move left on "Clear the jelly!" levels. Example: You have 6 moves left and you just cleared all the jelly. 18 fish will spawn and clear cells.

Source: http://candy-crush-saga.wikia.com/wiki/Levels

> Jelly - for every move remaining, three candy fish come on the screen and start eating the candies at random, giving you more points.

Comment: You just repeated what I said earlier.

Comment: @YoungGuilo No, that doesn't seem to be the case.